# WHERE with CASE and null checking

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, null, where-clause

i have a problem with a CASE statement in a WHERE clause. In my query i want to get rows which are before a date. The date is check on 3 columns. `date1` is NOT NULL so i dont need there a NULL check, but dates `date2` and `date3` can be NULL so i want to check for nulls and accordingly check the date condition. I tried two approaches but cant figure out how to do it right. Can you help?

Query 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    docs
WHERE
    date1 < '20120601'
    AND CASE
        WHEN date2 IS NOT NULL AND date3 IS NOT NULL THEN date2 < '20120601' 
        WHEN date2 IS NOT NULL AND date3 IS NULL THEN date2 < '20120601'
        WHEN date2 IS NULL AND date3 IS NOT NULL THEN date3 < '20120601'
    END
```

This gives and error in the first when: `Incorrect syntax near '<'.`

I modified my query to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    docs
WHERE
    date1 < '20120601'
    AND CASE
        WHEN date2 IS NOT NULL AND date3 IS NOT NULL AND date2 < '20120601' THEN TRUE 
        WHEN date2 IS NOT NULL AND date3 IS NULL AND date2 < '20120601' THEN TRUE
        WHEN date2 IS NULL AND date3 IS NOT NULL AND date3 < '20120601' THEN TRUE
    END
```

and got another error: `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'END'.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    docs
WHERE (date1 < '20120601')
OR    (date2 IS NOT NULL AND date2 < '201205601')
OR    (date2 IS NULL AND date3 IS NOT NULL AND date3 < '20120601')
```

Comment: Thanks thats it. Maybe not 100% i wanted, but thanks to this i found a mistake in my business logic. Now everthik works. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

```
where
date1 < '20120601'
    and
coalesce(date2, date3, '20000101') < '20120601'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
SELECT *
FROM
    docs
WHERE date1 < '20120601'
  AND ISNULL(date2, '20120601') < '20120601'
  AND ISNULL(date3, '20120601') < '20120601'
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct ANSWER is:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    docs
WHERE
    date1 < '20120601' AND
        ((date2 IS NOT NULL AND date3 IS NOT NULL AND date2 < '20120601') OR 
         (date2 IS NOT NULL AND date3 IS NULL AND date2 < '20120601') OR
         (date2 IS NULL AND date3 IS NOT NULL AND date3 < '20120601'))
```